# Does not redirect page after UploadComplete in AsyncFileUpload c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload

I am using `Ajax AsyncFileUpload` in `asp.net`. It is working fine in uploading image but don't know why it is redirecting to same page with some querystring `OnUploadComplete`. I don't want to reload page. How to solve this ?
**My Code is as below:**

```
function uploadComplete() {
    document.getElementById('<%=lblPhotoUpload.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Quiz Image Uploaded Successfully.";
     $("#UploadQuizImageProcess").hide();
}

function uploadError() {
     document.getElementById('<%=lblPhotoUpload.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "File Upload Failed.";
     $("#UploadQuizImageProcess").hide();
}
function uploadQuizImageStart() {
     $("#UploadQuizImageProcess").show();
}

<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="fuPhoto" runat="server" UploadingBackColor="#779ED3" CompleteBackColor="#179406" ThrobberID="imgLoad" OnUploadedComplete="QuizImageUploadComplete" OnClientUploadStarted="uploadQuizImageStart" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" OnClientUploadError="uploadError" UploaderStyle="Traditional" />
<span id="UploadQuizImageProcess" style="display: none">
<img src="../images/uploading.gif" alt="Upload" /></span>
<asp:Label ID="lblPhotoUpload" runat="server" CssClass="lbler"></asp:Label>

protected void QuizImageUploadComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fuPhoto.HasFile)
        {
            string filename = "";
            filename = "quiz" + ".jpg";

            // Save Image
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

is it not per design in asp.net webforms, that a post goes allways back to the same page ?

In your case it goes then in the QuizImageUploadComplete method.
So you could do a response.redirect("someulr.aspx") at the end of this method to get to another page

Comment: I don't want it to be redirect at any page. I want it there as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

```
onuploadedcomplete: This is a server side event which will be executed once the uploading is complete.
```

Comment: I'm not facing issues with `querystrings`. Tested in `IE 11` & `Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m`

Comment: I have tested it in Latest version of Mozilla and Chrome.

Comment: I'll try with Mozilla once.you sure in  chrome is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any issue with the code which you have pasted here.

As your control has **runat="server"** so anyways on uploading a file, a postback is bound to occur.

Could you check if there are any issues in your **Page_Load** .